# Only the first element is being read while processing XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm having some trouble with reading XML files in PHP. I'm not very skilled in PHP, so I use this code snippet: [Article](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial156_How-to-read-XML-using-PHP-DOM.html).

This is the XML file I'm trying to read: http://pastebin.com/2dtMp5VH

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contentdata>
    <Games>
    <numberof>2</numberof>
        <nameof>
            <n1>Game1</n1>
            <n2>Game2</n2>
        </nameof>
     </Games>
     <Software>
    <numberof>1</numberof>
        <nameof>
            <n1>Software1</n1>
        </nameof>
     </Software>
</contentdata>
```

This is my PHP script, based on the article I gave: http://pastebin.com/d29ejxSJ

```
$objDOM = new DOMDocument(); 
$objDOM->load("content.xml");
$note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("Games"); 

foreach( $note as $value ) 
{ 
    $numberof = $value->getElementsByTagName("numberof"); 
    $numberof_  = $numberof->item(0)->nodeValue; 
    echo($numberof_." games found!<br />");

    $numberof = (integer)$numberof_;
    $nameof = $value->getElementsByTagName("nameof");
    $i = 1;
    foreach($nameof as $value2)
    {
        $n = (string)$i;
        $nameof_[$i] = $value2->getElementsByTagName("n".$n);
        $nameof_[$i] = $nameof_[$i]->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo(((string)$i).": ".$nameof_[$i]."<br />");
        $i++;
    }
}
```

The output should be this:
2 games found!
1: Game1
2: Game2

However, for some reason it only outputs the following:
2 games found!
1: Game1

What is wrong with my code? How to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you post the code in here?

Comment: I tried, but it gave some weird formatting results.

Answer (score 1):

Like @chris sayd, I think you make the second `foreach` on the bad node. 
Your second `foreach` target : `nameof` and not his content (n1, n2, ...)

With Simple XML:

```
$Games = $value->getElementsByTagName("nameof")->children();
foreach($Games as $value2)
{
   // Your code to parse <nX>
}
```

Comment: thanks *gg*, not familiar with php just checked the algorithm :-)

Comment: See at http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php, Simple is an easy way to parse XML.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look over SimpleXML function: [`simplexml_load_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php).

Answer (score 0):

We need to see your XML, to really help with this BUT...

I think you might be confusing elements and attributes.  In brief, XML is composed like this

```
<tagname attr1=5 attr2='arf'> BODY HERE </tagname>
```

In your case, I don't believe `numberof` and `nameof` are elements at all.  They seem to be attributes belonging to `Games` elements.

Use echoes or `var_dump` to show the contents of variables like `$notes` and `$numberof` I think you'll find they don't contain what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

In $value you are keeping a reference of the `Games` node which containes just one single `nameof` node. Then later you make

```
foreach($nameof as $value2)
```

which will be executed exactly one time because there is only one nameof node in it. Your $i will stay 1 so only game one will be printed out.

What you need to do is selecting all the "nX" nodes and iterating through them but not through the nameof nodes because theres only one of it. Alternatively you can change the for loop so that you iterate exactly as much as is written in `numberof`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem is iterating through all the child elements in the `<nameof>` tag.

try the following:

```
foreach($nameof as $node){
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
       echo '<br/>Node Name: '.$child->nodeName.' Node Value: '.$child->nodeValue.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

instead of your last `foreach` statement and observe the output

Answer (score 0):

You second `foreach` is wrong as it only evaluate after the `nameof` entries in `Games` which is currently one entry.

You will need to use your `nameof_` to iterate in your case:

```
$objDOM = new DOMDocument(); 
$objDOM->load("content.xml");
$note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("Games"); 

foreach( $note as $value ) 
{ 
    $numberof = $value->getElementsByTagName("numberof"); 
    $numberof_  = $numberof->item(0)->nodeValue; 
    echo($numberof_." games found!<br />\n");

    $numberof = (integer)$numberof_;
    $nameof = $value->getElementsByTagName("nameof");
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberof_; $i++)
    {
        $n = (string)$i;
        $nameof_[$i] = $nameof->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("n".$n);
        $nameof_[$i] = $nameof_[$i]->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo(((string)$i).": ".$nameof_[$i]."<br />\n");
    }
}
```

As a advisory take a closer look at your data definition -like @jon_darkstar suggested as well- it does not look very XMLish (eg easy automatic parseble).

If you for example use this format, parsing will be more easy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contentdata>
  <Games>
    <item name="Game1" />
    <item name="Game2" />
  </Games>
  <Software>
    <item name="Software1" />
  </Software>
</contentdata>
```

Which you can than parse using

```
$objDOM = new DOMDocument();
$objDOM->load("content.xml");
$gamesElements = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("Games");

foreach ($gamesElements as $gamesElement)
{
    $itemElements = $gamesElement->getElementsByTagName("item");
    echo ($itemElements->length . " games found!<br />\n");

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($itemElements as $itemElement) {
       $name = $itemElement->attributes->getNamedItem('name')->nodeValue;
       echo("$i: $name<br />\n");
       $i++;
    }
}
```